# Obj-C - Get the sum of all values in a key?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to get the sum of all values (numbers) in key 'cost' in my NSDictionary (self.itemDetails).

```
NSNumber *sum = [self.itemDetails valueForKey:@"@sum.cost"];
```

That said, the above line causes my app to crash with the following.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
> reason: '[<__NSDictionaryM 0x281ab4e20> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
> class is not key value coding-compliant for the key sum.Item Cost.'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

This might clarify things. self.itemDetails (NSDictionary) is being added to an NSMutableArray (self.allItems). Here's the structure of my returned array of dictionaries. I'm trying to calculate the sum of all 'cost' keys:

```
[55155:2221932] All of the items in here (
        {
        cost = 30;
        description = Test;
        name = Test;
        rate = 5;
    },
        {
        cost = 50;
        description = Test;
        name = Test;
        rate = 5;
    }
)
```

Comment: The keypath is @“@sum.Item Cost” but I’m wondering if that space will bork things up too . https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: @WarrenBurton See my edit above, made the correction - but yes, this causes my app to crash :/

Comment: What about “valueForKeyPath:” as that’s a keypath your trying to use

Comment: @WarrenBurton When I use valueForKeyPath, I get the following crash error back: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryM 0x281038d60> valueForKeyPath:]: this class does not implement the sum operation.'

Comment: Ahhh never mind, figured it out. I think I confused myself ha ha. I was trying to grab the sum from self.itemDetails and I should've been grabbing it from self.allItems. Moron moment on my part O_O

Comment: Please delete the question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
NSNumber *sum = [self.allItems valueForKey:@"@sum.cost"];
```

Comment: By changing the question, it's not clear anymore why you had to ask. This is bad for people having the same problem and finding this question.

Comment: Ahh apologies, didnt realize that. I'll change it back :) @dasdom

Comment: Done - and left the later realizations under 'Edit'. Thanks @dasdom!

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over all dictionaries and add the costs. Like this:

```
NSInteger totalCosts = 0;
for (item in self.allItems) {
  totalCosts += [item[@"cost"] integerValue];
}
```